# How do I migrate from woocommerce_product_tax_class to woocommerce_product_get_tax_class?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I currently define the following in `functions.php`:

```
function wc_no_tax($tax_class, $product) {
  $id = $product->get_id();
  $price = $product->get_price();

  if ($id == 12345 && $price < 999) {
    $tax_class = 'Zero Rate';
  }

  return $tax_class;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_product_tax_class', 'wc_no_tax', 1, 2);
```

But I get the following debug notice:

> The "woocommerce_product_tax_class" hook uses out of date data structures and is deprecated since version 3.2.6! Use woocommerce_product_get_tax_class instead.

Is this as simple as updating the filter name?

Comment: Yes it is as simple as updating the filter hook name…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Just you need to update the filter name only like

```
function wc_no_tax( $tax_class, $product ) {
    $tax_class = 'zero-rate';
    return $tax_class;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_tax_class', 'wc_no_tax', 1, 2 );
```

I hope this is working for you.

Answer (score 1):

For variation fix you can use:

```
add_filter( "woocommerce_product_variation_get_tax_class", "wc_no_tax", 1, 2 );
```